# Why the button "Tree Hierarchy" in Folder Diff of Perforce disabled?

Tags: treeview, perforce, p4v, file-diffs

I have a problem when using Perforce.

I'm using P4V, but don't know the Perforce Server version.

There are often some files in our project that don't need to be version-controlled. And I found a way to exclude folders or files from Perforce by editing the Workspace View.

Using `"-//depot/. //Perforce/..."` or `"-//depot/*.dll //Perforce/*.dll"` I could exclude all files or folders in a path. Then the Folder Diff will mark them with "Excluded Folder". The world is clean.

BUT! there are a lot of projects, and each of them has the same folders that we don't need like "bin" "obj", and with WebStorm there are ".idea"s, and with ReSharper there are a lot of folders starts with `"_ReSharper"`, very disgusting.

With the articles [here](http://www.google.com/notebook/public/17393756076936429562/BDTyaIgoQwbaRgM0h) and [here](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/o.fspecs.html#1040647), the wildcards (`...\*`) seem to be put in the middle of path, like `"//Perforce/.../bin/..."`, to let Folder Diff exclude every descendant folder names "bin".

But there is the problem. When I use "Diff Against.." Then the Folder Diff view shows up. All the files are not shown in tree view but in list view. The button "Show files in a tree hierarchy" up there is disabled. And the most important thing is that excluded folders /files in workspace view are lying down there.

When I delete the descendant folder path, it turns normal with tree view and marked "exclude folders"

I have no idea about that. Could anyone tell me what happened there?

Comment: Are the files that don't need to be version controlled actually stored in Perforce, or are they only showing up because you're using Workspace View, and not Depot View?

Comment: I found out that Perforce cannot handle complex view path with wildcards like "//Perforce/.../bin/...",so they just disable the Tree Hierarchy view.How rude they are.